# Chart.js label on bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js on a project due to its MIT license instead of the Highcharts framework. There is one thing that can be easily done on highcharts that I cannot seem to do with Charts.js, which is having labels on top of my bars charts, [such as in the demo below](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked):

[image]

In highcharts [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.dataLabels) those numbers on each stack of this bar chart is configued in this manner:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
```

I've extensively read [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) and did not find a way of accomplishing the same visualization nor examples in forums. **Is there a way of showing numbers over the bars using Chart.js barcharts?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do this with Chart.js. However you need the [datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bar.html) plugin. In this script you can see how it is implemented. With this plugin charts of type `'bar'` will automatically add labels to the center.

```js
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("stack-chart");
var stackChart1 = new Chart(ctx2, {
  type: 'bar',
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{

        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{

        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
      labels: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontColor: '#595d6e',
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          return;
        },
        color: '#fff',
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels: ['ㅇㅇ마트', 'ㅂㅂ프라자', 'ㅈㅈ랜드', 'ㅁㅁ마트', 'ㄴㄴ플러스'],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "#5e63b4",
      data: [5600, 5600, 10000, 4600, 5600]
    }, {
      backgroundColor: "#e11738",
      data: [6000, 3000, 1600, 6400, 2300]
    }]
  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/0.7.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="stack-chart" width="1360" height="450"></canvas>
```